# add Static Text into text widget with Cloud store snapshot

Tags: flutter

I Have this piece of code and I want add some static text into it along with Dynamic text retrieved from cloud firestore.
The result I want to reach is:

Text('**Welcome** ["name"]'),

the piece of code  with the text widget is:

```
Text(snapshot.data.documents[index].data["name"]),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Text("Welcome ${snapshot.data.documents[index].data["name"]}");
```